# MemCached security concern

Tags: php, security, memcached

I see that one only needs the host ip address and port number to connect to a memcached instance running on the server.

How do i make sure of any security concerns? This way, if anyone knows my server's ip address, he can fetch out data out of my memcached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Memcached's SASL authentication to require proper credentials when connecting to the server. On top of that, you can also setup a secure proxy such as stunnel and authenticate the clients using certificates.

Note that both SASL and SSL are supported by http://redislabs.com/memcached-cloud.

Answer (score 3):

If your application and memcache are on the same server, the easiest way would be to restrict connections to localhost.

You can do this setting this option `-l 127.0.0.1`

Where your config file is located is dependent on the OS your using.

See this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/347621/memcache-basic-configuration) or this [Blog](https://coderwall.com/p/i2tcmg) for examples.

Comment: This was default in my installation. Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict to localhost but you can restrict to specified users on machine :] All have acces for data in memcache :]

Comment: You mean *can **not** restrict to specified users*, don't you?